# Trying to find alternative way to flatter the array of object in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to bulk update using sequlize ORM but i have to run loop for that that i dont want to so how i can do without loop

i have list of object in team that i have to update in database

code is

```
bulkupdate_transaction = async(contest_team_data:any,flag:number):Promise<any> =>{
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>{
            try{
                let data = []
                for(let index = 0; index < contest_team_data.length;index++){
                    data.push({
                        team_id: contest_team_data[index].team_id,
                        team_name: contest_team_data[index].team_name,
                        user_id: contest_team_data[index].user_id,
                        contest_id: contest_team_data[index].contest_id,
                        contest_date: contest_team_data[index].contest_date,
                        selected_symbols: contest_team_data[index].selected_symbols,
                        status: contest_team_data[index].status,
                        fees_paid: contest_team_data[index].fees_paid,
                        po_id: contest_team_data[index].po_id,
                        points: contest_team_data[index].points,
                        bonus_deduction: contest_team_data[index].bonus_deduction,
                        cash_deduction: contest_team_data[index].cash_deduction,
                        winning_deduction: contest_team_data[index].winning_deduction,
                        winning_prize: contest_team_data[index].winning_prize,
                        win: (contest_team_data[index].winning_prize > 0) ? true : false,
                        rank: contest_team_data[index].rank,
                        createdat: contest_team_data[index].createdat,
                        updatedat: new Date()
                    })
                }
                await Teams.bulkCreate(data  , {
                    updateOnDuplicate: ['points', 'rank','win','winning_prize']
                });
                resolve({success:true})
            }catch(error){
                console.log(error)
                reject({success:false})
            }
        })
    }
```

as you can see i have variable named contest_team_data that have value like that

```
[
teams {
    dataValues: {
      team_id: '4e1a430c-c697-457b-8b6f-b71e6990b6c3',
      po_id: 'ff1bdd59-272f-4c18-97bf-b54dbd8d0020',
      user_id: '15218145-d032-4971-b3f9-d2cb2a09adc9',
      selected_symbols: [Array],
      team_name: 'test 9',
      contest_id: '5c8fbd6f-fa57-40f8-97e6-ccc47f537764',
      contest_date: '2022-07-25',
      status: 'Live',
      fees_paid: 50,
      bonus_deduction: 5,
      winning_deduction: 0,
      cash_deduction: 45,
      createdat: 2022-07-25T05:38:40.824Z,
      purchaseOrder: [purchase_orders],
      points: '-137472',
      rank: 14
    }
},
teams {
    dataValues: {
      team_id: '5f73f75b-51c7-46c5-bdf5-0c61d25471f7',
      po_id: 'ff1bdd59-272f-4c18-97bf-b54dbd8d0020',
      user_id: '15218145-d032-4971-b3f9-d2cb2a09adc9',
      selected_symbols: [Array],
      team_name: 'test 14',
      contest_id: '5c8fbd6f-fa57-40f8-97e6-ccc47f537764',
      contest_date: '2022-07-25',
      status: 'Live',
      fees_paid: 50,
      bonus_deduction: 5,
      winning_deduction: 0,
      cash_deduction: 45,
      createdat: 2022-08-26T05:38:40.824Z,
      purchaseOrder: [purchase_orders],
      points: '-130864',
      rank: 13
    }
}
]
```

when i trying to pass contest_team_data in sequlize for bulk update getting error for getting null but i have value in object

now please any one can help to how to solve this.

Comment: what is ORM in this context?

Comment: please use punctuation marks, so we can understand your writing.

Comment: [bulkCreate](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-bulkCreate)?

Comment: @nullptr bulk create is like upinsert that do insert if value is not avalible other wise on conflict that do update the value of [points', 'rank','win','winning_prize'] here.

Comment: @helle  I used sequlize ORM and sorry for punctuation.

Comment: so what stands O_ R_ M_ for in that content?

Comment: @helle i did not get you

ORM is object-relational mapping in my context i sharing that i am using sequlize ORM because their is other ORM also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you should use a for loop to update all records based on a given array because Sequelize does not support such feature (basically most if not every DBMS do not support multi-record update for each record individually).